# Does using the HTML5 DOCTYPE break compatibility anywhere?

Tags: html, doctype

Are there any downsides to prefixing my HTML documents with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Will it break compatibility anywhere significant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not.

This doctype was chosen for HTML5 because it is the bare minimum required to invoke standards mode in browsers that care about such things. Provided your markup is standards compliant you should not have any issues.

Browsers that don't care about the doctype will just do what they've always done.

Edit: Here is an [overview of the different modes](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), and the impact this has on different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't.  HTML5 is in its first draft still, so there shouldn't be any issue.  Just to be sure though, you can use the validation service to check.

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Validation has _nothing_ to do with compatibility.

Comment: Yeah, my main question is whether including the tag will blow up someone's computer running, say, IE5. Not that I care about IE5 support at all, but still.

Comment: @Slaks If code does not validate, then chances are it isn't standard and therefore may not be compatible on all browsers.

Comment: @MGZero: True.   However, compatibility is much more the valid code.  He's specifically asking whether the _standard_ new DOCTYPE will cause issues.

Comment: @Slaks I was under the impression he was asking about validation, as switching from the 4.01 transitional DTD to the strict for example can cause some issues.  But yes, your interpretation seems more accurate.